# Allow a fixed div to scroll again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

This is a little complex so please refer to this page for an example: [No Nay Never post page](http://nonaynever.net/15150/will-burnley-go-down/)

As you scroll down the page, the image on the left (the whole left div, actually) sticks to the top of the page.

I want this to stop being fixed, and scroll again, when the image reaches the 'comments' section at the bottom.

I can't fathom how to do this - any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This could be done using scrollTop()

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: For a quick example, it should behave like the images on here: http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-04/19/new-dinosaur

Comment: Thanks Sprottenwells, I'll look into that this afternoon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start scrolling you make the image `fixed` after a certain `scrollTop` has been reached, I assume?

All you need to do know to give the element an `absolute` position when a greater `scrollTop` has been reached. The absolute position in question should be derived from the top offset of the comments section and the height of the sticky image.

Comment: Thanks David. Your assumption is indeed correct, and that explanation makes sense. I'll try and tackle this, thanks for your quick response and helpful advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this using a scroll function that checks the page position each time the user scrolls

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //event will fire each time a user scrolls
    //get the top page position
    var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    //Evaluate the position, do what you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The site in the example is using scrollTop. At some scrolling point there is a class "sticky" added to the div (#left) with a javascript function:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#left");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $div.addClass("sticky"); 
    }
    else {
        $div.removeClass("sticky");
    }
}
```

the given position data("top") is read in this little snippet

```
$("#left").data("top", $("#left").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

The comment speaks for itself. The original position is read,

This is the "sticky" class:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```